# DropDownList control right-click event

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, events, mfc, mouseevent

I have a dropdownlist control in my MFC dialog.

[image]

TIn it will be a list with almost all Windows Messages. Being so many, the user will find them harder. So I want that when the user right-clicks the drop-down, a window should open to provide some search elements.

I don't know exactly how to make the right-click event.

This is my .rc file code:

```
    COMBOBOX        IDC_WM,98,7,152,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_AUTOHSCROLL | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

I tried with "Create event handler" ption in Visual Studio, but I didn't find the right-click event.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dialog that is parent for the combobox override PreTranslateMessage.

Add the following code:

```
BOOL CMyDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
  if(pMsg->message == WM_RBUTTONUP)
  {
    if(pMsg->hwnd == m_myCombobox.GetSafeHwnd())
    {
      // do advanced search here

      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```